# Login component react-native

Tags: react-native

I am making a react-native application.

I am trying to find out how can I show or hide the login component on the basis of a token stored. If the token is present in the storage, it would skip the login screen to the dashboard.

Else it will show login screen.

Here is the code to the app.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import Login from './components/Login';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

export default function App() {
  var [ token, setToken ] = useState('');

  function loginHandler(recievedToken) {
    setToken(recievedToken);
  }
  async function _readData() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Token');
      console.log(value);
      if (value !== null) {
        // We have data!!
        loginHandler(value)
      } else {
        loginHandler(null);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
    }
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Login getToken={_readData()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put conditional statement in your code.
Try this code out.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, AsyncStorage, ActivityIndictor } from 'react-native';

import Login from './components/Login';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

export default function App() {
  var [ token, setToken ] = useState('');
  var [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(true);

  function loginHandler(recievedToken) {
    setToken(recievedToken);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  async function _readData() {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Token');
      console.log(value);
      if (value !== null) {
        // We have data!!
        loginHandler(value)
      } else {
        loginHandler(null);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
    }
  };

    if( loading ) {
        <ActivityIndictor/>
    }

    if(token == null){
    return (
        <View>
        <Login getToken={_readData()} />
        </View>
    );
    } else {
        return (
        <View>
        <Dashboard />
        </View>
    );
    }
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Let me know if some error or correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here AuthStack is Login Screen and BottomNavigation is DashBoard.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AuthStackScreen from "./routes/AuthStack";
import BottomNavigation from "./routes/BottomNavigator";
import firebase from "./config/firebase";

export default App = () => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState(false);
  const checkLoginIn = () => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        setIsLogin(true);
      } else {
        setIsLogin(false);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLoginIn();
  }, []);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLogin ? <BottomNavigation /> : <AuthStackScreen />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

Comment: I doubt this would work. Please check the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

In my case

I just used `initialRouteName`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import Home from './components/Home';
import Login from './components/Login';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  routeName: 'Login',
};
}

async componentDidMount() {
const token = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('token'));
if (token !== null) {
  this.setState({
    routeName: 'Bluetooth',
  });
}
SplashScreen.hide();
}

render() {
return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={this.state.routeName}
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
      }}>
      <>
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
);
}
}
```